# Spark: Find Each Partition Size for RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What's the best way of finding each partition size for a given RDD. I'm trying to debug a skewed Partition issue, I've tried this:

```
l = builder.rdd.glom().map(len).collect()  # get length of each partition
print('Min Parition Size: ',min(l),'. Max Parition Size: ', max(l),'. Avg Parition Size: ', sum(l)/len(l),'. Total Partitions: ', len(l))
```

It works fine for small RDDs, but for bigger RDDs, it is giving OOM error. My idea is that `glom()` is causing this to happen. But anyway, just wanted to know if there is any better way to do it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use:

```
builder.rdd.mapPartitions(lambda it: [sum(1 for _ in it)])
```

Comment: It would be good if you could explain with the OP's approach is not working in his case and why this approach **is** working ... ?

Comment: It gives error "AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'"

Comment: `glom()` is supposed to return an RDD or the entire data contained within a shuffle partition. So instead of returning entire rows of data and then computing length on the dataset, he is just adding 1 for each of those rows for each partition.

Answer (score 12):

While the answer by @LostInOverflow works great. I've found another way to find the size as well as index of each partition, using the code below. Thanks to [this awesome post.](https://datarus.wordpress.com/2015/05/04/fighting-the-skew-in-spark/)

Here is the code:

```
l = test_join.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(lambda x,it: [(x,sum(1 for _ in it))]).collect()
```

and then you can get the max and min size partitions using this code:

```
min(l,key=lambda item:item[1])
max(l,key=lambda item:item[1])
```

Finding the key of the skewed partition, we can further debug the content of the that partition, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone came here looking for Scala solution:

```scala
// For DataFrame:
df.mapPartitions(it => Iterator(it.size))

// For RDD:
df.rdd.mapPartitions(it => Iterator(it.size))
```