# How to write dataset object to excel in spark java?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-excel

I Am reading excel file using **com.crealytics.spark.excel** package.
Below is the code to read an excel file in spark java.

```
    Dataset<Row> SourcePropertSet = sqlContext.read()
               .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
               .option("location", "D:\\5Kto10K.xlsx")
               .option("useHeader", "true")
               .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
               .option("inferSchema", "true")
               .option("addColorColumns", "false")
               .load("com.databricks.spark.csv");
```

But I tried with the same  **(com.crealytics.spark.excel)** package to write dataset object to an excel file in spark java.

```
    SourcePropertSet.write()
          .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
          .option("useHeader", "true")
          .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
          .option("inferSchema", "true")
          .option("addColorColumns", "false").save("D:\\resultset.xlsx");
```

But i am getting below error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource
>   does not allow create table as select.

And even I tried with **org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel** package also.
below is the code for that.

```
    SourcePropertSet.write()
             .format("org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel")
             .option("write.locale.bcp47", "de") 
             .save("D:\\result");
```

i have added following dependencies in my **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
              <groupId>com.github.zuinnote</groupId>
              <artifactId>hadoopoffice-fileformat</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.0</version>
          </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.zuinnote</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hadoopoffice-ds_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

But I am getting below error.

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.zuinnote.hadoop.office.format.mapreduce.ExcelFileOutputFormat.getSuffix(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
>   from class org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel.ExcelOutputWriterFactory

**Please help me to write dataset object to an excel file in spark java.**

Comment: Check my answer for similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799949/how-to-write-dataset-to-a-excel-file-using-hadoop-office-library-in-apache-spark/44806022#44806022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the library you chose, [com.crealytics.spark.excel](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel), does not have any code related to *writing* excel files. Underneath it uses [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/index.html) for reading Excel files, there are also few [examples](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html).

The good news are that CSV is a valid Excel file, and you may use [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) to write it. You need to change your code like this:

```
sourcePropertySet.write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .save("D:\\resultset.csv");
```

Keep in mind that Spark makes 1 output file per partition, and you might want to do `.repartition(1)` to have exactly one result file.

Comment: I have already done writing dataset object to CSV file, but CSV files don't support few formats( eg: if a single cell contains any comma or other special characters it will split that single cell as multiple cells). Hence I need to write to an excel file, is there any approaches are there to do the same using Apache Spark?

Comment: If I understand you right and you need to write a value that contains comma (say, a tuple like this: `(1, "Hello, world!")`), then CSV standard defines escaping rules. Instead of `1, Hello, world!` you should have `1, "Hello, world!"`. CSV libraries are capable to do that, for sure `com.databricks.spark.csv` is capable of that.

Comment: Spark 2.x has in-built CSV support (com.databricks.spark.csv is for Spark 1.x). You can now use format("csv"). Another supported syntax is dataframe.write.option("header", "true").csv("D:\\resultset.csv").

Comment: .coalesce(1) would be a better approach over .repartition(1)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610971/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce

Answer (score 0):

The error you face when writing comes from an old version of the HaodoopOffice library. Please make sure that you have only version 1.0.3 or better 1.0.4 as a dependency. Can you provide your build file? The following should work:

```
 SourcePropertSet.write()
             .format("org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel")
             .option("spark.write.useHeader",true)
             .option("write.locale.bcp47", "us") 
             .save("D:\\result");
```

Version 1.0.4 of the Spark2 data source for HadoopOffice also supports inferring the schema when reading:

```
 Dataset<Row> SourcePropertSet = sqlContext.read()
               .format("org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel")
               .option("spark.read.useHeader", "true")
               .option("spark.read.simpleMode", "true")
               .load("D:\\5Kto10K.xlsx");
```

Please note that it is not recommended to mix different Excel data sources based on POI in one application.

More information here: https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/spark-hadoopoffice-ds