# How to write Dataset to a excel file using hadoop office library in apache spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-excel

Currently I am using **com.crealytics.spark.excel** to read an Excel file, but using this library I can't  write the dataset to an Excel file.

This [link](https://snippetessay.wordpress.com/2017/01/08/readingwriting-excel-documents-with-the-hadoopoffice-library-on-hadoop-and-spark-first-release) says that using hadoop office library (`org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel`) we can read and write to Excel files

**Please help me to write dataset object to an excel file in spark java.**

Comment: what's wrong with csv?

Comment: CSV files don't support few formats
( eg: if a single cell contains any comma or other special characters it will split that single cell as multiple cells). 
Hence I need to write to an excel file, is there any approaches are there to do the same using Apache Spark? –

Comment: Using existing tools, you could save the data to Hive, and then use Hue to download/generate an Excel file. You can also check what logic in Hue actually provides this Excel file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel` for both reading and writing excel file using Dataset. Examples are given at https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/spark-hadoopoffice-ds/. However, there is one issue if you read the Excel in Dataset and try to write it in another Excel file. Please see the issue and workaround in scala at https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice/issues/12.

I have written a sample program in Java using `org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel` and workaround given at that link. Please see if this helps you.

```
public class SparkExcel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //spark session
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("SparkExcel")
                .master("local[*]")
                .getOrCreate();

        //Read
        Dataset<Row> df = spark
                .read()
                .format("org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel")
                .option("read.locale.bcp47", "de")
                .load("c:\\temp\\test1.xlsx");

        //Print
        df.show();
        df.printSchema();

        //Flatmap function
        FlatMapFunction<Row, String[]> flatMapFunc = new FlatMapFunction<Row, String[]>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<String[]> call(Row row) throws Exception {
                ArrayList<String[]> rowList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
                List<Row> spreadSheetRows = row.getList(0);
                for (Row srow : spreadSheetRows) {
                    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
                    arr.add(srow.getString(0));
                    arr.add(srow.getString(1));
                    arr.add(srow.getString(2));
                    arr.add(srow.getString(3));
                    arr.add(srow.getString(4));
                    rowList.add(arr.toArray(new String[] {}));
                }
                return rowList.iterator();
            }
        };

        //Apply flatMap function
        Dataset<String[]> df2 = df.flatMap(flatMapFunc, spark.implicits().newStringArrayEncoder());

        //Write
        df2.write()
           .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
           .format("org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel")
           .option("write.locale.bcp47", "de")
           .save("c:\\temp\\test2.xlsx");

    }
}
```

I have tested this code with Java 8 and Spark 2.1.0. I am using maven and added dependency for `org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel` from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.zuinnote/spark-hadoopoffice-ds_2.11/1.0.3

Comment: We are not able to add header information into the excel which we are writing
Is there any options to write the headers to output excel file, Please help me to do the same

Comment: How are you creating Dataset - by reading existing file or new Dateset using schema? If reading existing file then first row could be header. Can you please post a separate question with details and sample code.

Comment: I just want to notify you that the current HadoopOffice library 1.0.4 supports reading/writing of headers as well as reading a file into a dataframe with simple datatypes (cf. https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/spark-hadoopoffice-ds). Some other notable things in 1.0.4 is the support of templates for writing (to include diagrams etc.) and reading/writing in low footprint mode (with a low memory/CPU footprint) based on Event and Streaming APIs of Apache POI.