# pyspark lot of stages in toPandas() for just a few records

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We are having issues trying to do a toPandas() function from a Spark Dataframe.

The DF has only 1200 records, and Spark creates a Job of 77 large and expensive Stages to do it.

This is what we are doing to workaround the problem:

1. df.repartition(1) after the toPandas() function.
2. a. save the DF to HDP as csv that populates an external table;
   b. query for that table; c. toPandas()

Any ideas to reduce the Job?

Thanks in advance, Max.

Code:
`return_per_action_partial = return_per_action_partial.toPandas()`

**UPDATE 10/24/2017:
We find out that Spark does not have those records in memory, it actually has the plan to get them. So, it creates a Job of 77 Stages, redoing all prior steps.
We are trying to make checkpoints, consolidating partial DFs as tables into HDP.
Does anyone know any better/native solution?**

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: you can try `coalesce` instead of `repartition`, since you are looking to decrease the number of partitions. This will be less compuationally expensive as you are avoiding a full shuffle. See a comprehensive explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610971/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce

Comment: @ags29, I made an update. Please check it when you can.

Comment: @William Hampshire, I made an update. Please check it when you can.