# save data into single file in hdfs using spark

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to save a json data into single file in hdfs. 
currently my approach is to save data into hdfs using spark then merge the data into local (local_tmp_file) and then move it into hdfs (dest)

```
getmerge_command = 'hdfs dfs -getmerge ' + dest + ' ' + local_tmp_file
move_command = 'hdfs dfs -moveFromLocal ' + local_tmp_file + ' ' + dest
```

the problem happened when there is a lot of process run at the same time and use the temporary local storage which makes the disk full.
Is anyone have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use coalesce() if we are decreasing the partitions as it more optimized version of repartition(), as it avoids full shuffling of data.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("json").save("test_file")
```

For more details on repartition and coalesce,check this,
[Spark - repartition() vs coalesce()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610971/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce)

Comment: coalesce(1) and repartition(1) are same in functionality as whole data has to be transferred in one partition there has to be a shuffle and it will be same for both the operations, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: The problem with this approach is the spark driver will be overquota since all the data will be pulled into it.

Answer (score 0):

when you are saving the data use repartition(1)

`df.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("json").save("test_file")`