# Spark save(write) parquet only one file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

if i write

```
dataFrame.write.format("parquet").mode("append").save("temp.parquet")
```

in temp.parquet folder 
i got the same file numbers as the row numbers

i think i'm not fully understand about parquet but is it natural?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@coalesce(numPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) before *write* operation

`dataFrame.coalesce(1).write.format("parquet").mode("append").save("temp.parquet")`

---

**EDIT-1**

Upon a closer look, the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@coalesce(numPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) do warn about `coalesce`

> However, if you're doing a drastic coalesce, e.g. to numPartitions =
>   1, this may result in your computation taking place on fewer nodes
>   than you like (e.g. one node in the case of numPartitions = 1)

Therefore as [suggested by **@Amar**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51630278/3679900), it's better to use [`repartition`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@repartition(numPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T])

Comment: I have read elsewhere that coalesce is more performant. Who should we believe?

Comment: While `coalesce` [minimizes data-movement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31612810/3679900), the resulting *partitions* are not necessarily (in fact, unlikely) of same-size. So it's really a trade-off between less shuffle-*overhead* and (*almost*) equal-sized partitions. **[1]** Therefore, *in general*, it's best to use `coalesce` and fall back to `repartition` only when degradation is observed **[2]** However in this particular case of `numPartitions=1`, the docs stress that `repartition` would be a better choice

Comment: I meant the shuffle and always had the impression this is the most important aspect, but I take your point, which was my point. Interesting.

Comment: Thank you y2k-shubham, the bluephantom I've got what i want!!

Answer (score 17):

You can set partitions as 1 to save as single file

```
dataFrame.repartition(1).write.format("parquet").mode("append").save("temp.parquet")
```

Comment: Note that `repartition(1)` should come before `write` since it is a method of [`Dataset`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@repartition(numPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) and not [`DataFrameWriter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter)

Answer (score 6):

Although previous answers are correct you have to understand repercusions that come after repartitioning or coalescing to a single partition. All your data will have to be transferred to a single worker just to immediately write it to a single file.

As it is repeatidly mentioned throughout the internet, you should use `repartition` in this scenario despite the shuffle step that gets added to the execution plan. This step helps to use your cluster's power instead of sequentially merging files.

There is at least one alternative worth mentioning. You can write a simple script that would merge all the files into a single one. That way you will avoid generating massive network traffic to a single node of your cluster.

Comment: Thank you battaio.
Now i'm searching about repartition and coalesce!!