# Will Spark Coalesce perform Shuffle

Tags: apache-spark

Assume I have a 8 node Spark cluster with 8 partitions (i.e each node has 1 partitions)
Now if I try to reduce the number of partitions to 4 by using coalesce(4), 
1. Will coalesce perform shuffle ?
2. If yes, then in which nodes will the newly created 4 partitions reside ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark - repartition() vs coalesce()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610971/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce)

Comment: Thanks Nabongs... Shuffle means moving the data from one node to another node across network. In this case,
Node 1 = 1,2,3
Node 2 = 4,5,6
Node 3 = 7,8,9
Node 4 = 10,11,12
Then coalesce down to 2 partitions:

Node 1 = 1,2,3 + (10,11,12)
Node 3 = 7,8,9 + (4,5,6) ..... 
Now data has moved from Node 4 to Node 1, Is this not a shuffle ?

Can you please help me to understand.

Comment: Hi Praveen, Please look into the answer that i have given, please accept answer if you feel its right, or ask your doubts

Answer (score 4):

If You Check Spark API documentation of Coalesce. Then that is following

```
coalesce(int numPartitions, boolean shuffle, scala.math.Ordering<T> ord)
```

by default the shuffle Flag is False. Repartition calls same method by changing shuffle flag to True. With This info, Now let us answer your question

To Change Number of Partitions From 8 to 4, Shuffle has to happen. But here you are explicitly saying No to shuffle. **So Number of Partitions in This case will not change.**

even If you Try to Increase number of Partitions, It will not change. Since shuffle flag is False. Hope This Helps

Cheers!

Comment: Number of partitions do decrease with false

Comment: Yes... If Flag is set to False, No of Partitions will decrease, By changing flag to true and setting number of partitions, you can increase the number of partitions also. Thats what i Meant

Answer (score 3):

Coalesce by default has shuffling flag set to False.

If you have to increase the partitions, you can either use coalesce with shuffle flag set to true(with false, partition remains unchanged) or use repartition

If you are decreasing partitions, better to use coalesce with flag set to False as it avoids full shuffle unlike repartition where shuffling is guaranteed.
Coalesce with false shuffling moves data on 1 partition to another existing partition thereby avoiding full shuffle giving better performance.
say, data from partitions 5,6,7,8 will be moved to existing partitions 1,2,3,4 rather than shuffling the data of all 8 partitions

Determining on which node data resides is decided by the partitioner you are using

Answer (score 0):

coalesce(numpartitions) - used to reduce the no of partitions without shuffling
coalesce(numpartitions,shuffle=false) - spark won't perform any shuffling because of shuffle = false option and used to reduce the no of partitions
coalesce(numpartitions,shuffle=true) -  spark will perform shuffling because of shuffle = true option and used to reduce and increase the partitions

Example : 
Assume rdd with 8 partitions initially

rdd.coalesce(4) - will results 4 partitons as output
rdd.coalesce(4,false) - will results 4 partitons as output
rdd.coalesce(10,false) - will results 8 partitons as output (shuffle = false will be able to reduce the partitons but not able to increase)
rdd.coalesce(4,true) - will results 4 partitons as output
rdd.coalesce(10,true) - will results 10 partitons as output (shuffle = true will be able to able to increase partitons)