# How to repartition Spark dataframe depending on row count?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I wrote a simple program that request a huge database. To export my result, I wrote this function:

```
result.coalesce(1).write.options(Map("header" -> "true", "delimiter"  > ";")).csv(mycsv.csv)
```

I use the `coalesce` method to have only get one file as an output. The problem is that the result file contains more than one million lines. So, I couldn't open it in Excel...

So, I thought about using a method (or write my own function using a for loop) that can create partitions related to the number of the lines in my file. But I have no idea how can I do this.

My idea is that if I have less than one million line, I will have one partition. If I have more than one million => two partitions, 2 millions => 3 partitions and so on.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change the number of partition depending on the number of rows in the dataframe.

For example:

```
val rowsPerPartition = 1000000
val partitions = (1 + df.count() / rowsPerPartition).toInt

val df2 = df.repartition(numPartitions=partitions)
```

Then write the new dataframe to a csv file as before.

**Note:** it may be required to use `repartition` instead of `coalesce` to make sure the number of rows in each partition are roughly equal, see [Spark - repartition() vs coalesce()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610971/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce).

Comment: Any idea how to do that without having to call 2 actions, which could be expensive computationally?

Comment: @Timmeh: if you know approximately how large your dataframe is then there is no need for the count. Otherwise, I don't think there is any alternative if you want to adjust the number of partitions depending on the size.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it's a dynamic job, so size of output can very significantly. I found the maxRecordsPerFile option which might be sufficient