# Use pyspark to partition 100 rows from csv file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to group 100 rows of a large csv file (100M+ rows) to send to a Lambda function.
I can use SparkContext to have a workaround like this:

```py
csv_file_rdd = sc.textFile(csv_file).collect()

count = 0
buffer = []
while count < len(csv_file_rdd):
    buffer.append(csv_file_rdd[count])
    count += 1
    if count % 100 == 0 or count == len(csv_file_rdd):
        # Send buffer to process
        print("Send:", buffer)
        # Clear buffer
        buffer = []
```

but there must be a more elegant solution. I've tried using `SparkSession` and `mapPartition` but I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: I know. That's why I said it's a workaround.

Comment: This isn't any more than a workaround than using Python to directly read the file with `open(csv_file).readlines()`

Comment: I think you're right. But your comment doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It's not meant to, thus why it's a comment

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your current data is not partitioned in any way (I mean its only one file), so iterating over it sequencially is a must. I suggest to load it as a data frame  `spark.read.csv(csv_file)` then repartition as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54286733/how-to-repartition-spark-dataframe-depending-on-row-count/54287693) and save to disk. Once it's saved you'll have a big number of files containing the specified number of records (100 in your case), taht can be used by other program to send to a Lambda (probably with a Pool of workers). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446445/python-multiprocessing-safely-writing-to-a-file) to get an idea. Probably is a naive idea but get's the job done.

Comment: Thank you! this is helpful.