# How to write to a singlefile from from spark rdd map and reduce operations

Tags: apache-spark, dictionary, rdd, reduce

I am trying to write to a text file after applying the map, reduce operations. The below code is creating 8 files, but I need only one file

```
df3.rdd.map(_.toSeq.map(_+"").reduce(_+" "+_)).saveAsTextFile("/home/ram/Desktop/test4")
```

Please suggest how to write content to a single file

Comment: use .coalesce(1) before save

Answer (score 1):

The best option is "coalesce".
The coalesce method reduces the number of partitions in a DataFrame.

here is the code for your question.

```
df3.coalesce(1).rdd.map(_.toSeq.map(_+"").reduce(_+" "+_)).saveAsTextFile("/home/ram/Desktop/test4")
```

Because it will give good performance by avoiding data movement.
please check the below link.

[Spark - repartition() vs coalesce()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610971/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce)

Answer (score 0):

It is creating multiple files because each partition is saved individually. If you need a single output file inside a folder then you can repartition or coalesce to write to a single file.

```
df3.repartition(1).rdd.map(_.toSeq.map(_+"").reduce(_+" "+_)).saveAsTextFile("/home/ram/Desktop/test4")
```