# Is one parquet files under the parquet folder a partition?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, partition

I saved my dataframe as parquet format

```
df.write.parquet('/my/path')
```

When checking on HDFS, I can see that there is 10 part-xxx.snappy.parquet files under the parquet directory /my/path

My question is: is one part-xxx.snappy.parquet file correspond to a partition of my dataframe ?

Comment: I am not sure if this question might be duplicated, please let me know if there is already similar question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, part-** files are created based on **`number of partitions`** in the dataframe while writing to HDFS.

To check `number of partitions` in the dataframe:

```
df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
```

To control number of files writing to filesystem we can use [`.repartition (or) .coalesce() (or) dynamically`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60817762/is-there-a-way-to-control-number-of-part-files-in-hdfs-created-from-spark-datafr/60817903#60817903) based on our requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this creates one file per Spark-partition.

Note, that you can also partition files by some attribute:

```
df.write.partitionBy("key").parquet("/my/path")
```

in such case Spark is going to create up to Spark-partition number of files for each parquet-partition. Common way to reduce number of files in such case is to repartition data by key before writing (this effectively creates one file per partition).