# Partitioning with pyspark not taking effect

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to make a good partition of the data in pyspark according to specific ID.

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
mysqlContext = HiveContext(sc) 
query_1= f"SELECT /*+ COALESCE(100) */ {fields_Str} FROM database_customer.customer_table where customer_id in ({customer_id_Str}) " 

df_1 = mysqlContext.sql(query_1)
```

where `fields_str` contains the fields used. and `customer_id_Str` contains 500 unique `customer_id`

When I want to get the number of partition using this line of code:

```
df_1.rdd.getNumPartitions()
```

I get 100 which is good. But when I run the following code

```
df_1 = df_1.repartition(500,"customer_id")
df_1.show(30,truncate=False)
```

It will take about 30 minutes of processing showing the following in the jobs page:
[image: JOb page]

It shows that there is 6020 jobs running. and it takes 30 minutes.
Even after the partition is done, when I re run  `df_1.show(30,truncate=False)`  it will take the same time.

Any idea why?

Comment: Please consider using coalesce when decreasing the nummer of partitions as repartition does a full data shuffle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610971/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce

Comment: @user4126670 but the coelesce part is already done in the SQL query, no?