# pyspark data frame join operation and write as json is very slow

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two large spark data frames, user details and user Relationship.
Both data frame has more than 20M records.

data frame join Join operation is very very slow. Please help me to improve join performance.

**DF details**

***user_df***

- One user should have multiple addresses.
- One user + address should have multiple networks

Schema

```
root
 |-- USERIDENTIFIER: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ADDRESSIDENTIFIER: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LATITUDE: decimal(15,12) (nullable = true)
 |-- LONGITUDE: decimal(15,12) (nullable = true)
 |-- USERNAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NETWORKIDENTIFIER: string (nullable = true)
```

sample data

```
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
|USERIDENTIFIER                  |ADDRESSIDENTIFIER               |LATITUDE       |LONGITUDE        |USERNAME                  |NETWORKIDENTIFIER               |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
|C9BBB242202692B589DC5E6AD1040229|0B60DA9CB69084711BC119CB7DB5A120|33.779730000000|-117.867278000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SPECIALISTS|0364142E829F4B9384C8023C3BD7194B|
|C9BBB242202692B589DC5E6AD1040229|0EBFEB7F15B503D7F34BA4650E561D4B|33.804552000000|-118.067973000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SPECIALISTS|0364142E829F4B9384C8023C3BD7194B|
|C9BBB242202692B589DC5E6AD1040229|0DC22C71A345C6750158E88D98D6671D|33.701665000000|-117.956545000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SPECIALISTS|0364142E829F4B9384C8023C3BD7194B|
|C9BBB242202692B589DC5E6AD1040229|086E9420C60A7D037FB127727967337B|33.780334000000|-117.863353000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SPECIALISTS|0364142E829F4B9384C8023C3BD7194B|
|C9BBB242202692B589DC5E6AD1040229|0E30A48D4829E093E60C7026351DFA04|33.780334000000|-117.863353000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SPECIALISTS|0364142E829F4B9384C8023C3BD7194B|
|97B177D33281DF30AFC9924294D1973D|33CF41F3F7AC69029EDD664DF569AE41|33.610987000000|-117.712710000000|Mary A Wilkinson          |0364142E829F4B9384C8023C3BD7194B|
|97B177D33281DF30AFC9924294D1973D|97612FEFFD5EA7664E566161CE9318EF|33.569658000000|-117.726847000000|Mary A Wilkinson          |0364142E829F4B9384C8023C3BD7194B|
|97B177D33281DF30AFC9924294D1973D|0779CA3DCA30B801B55AB8FE8EFE8E77|33.665445000000|-117.761503000000|Mary A Wilkinson          |0364142E829F4B9384C8023C3BD7194B|
|97B177D33281DF30AFC9924294D1973D|A8EFFB0D29B8628B9A3E993490FF6F8F|33.439137000000|-117.621570000000|Mary A Wilkinson          |0364142E829F4B9384C8023C3BD7194B|
|97B177D33281DF30AFC9924294D1973D|0779CA3DCA30B801B55AB8FE8EFE8E77|33.665445000000|-117.761503000000|Mary A Wilkinson          |06702F3EAF8846A450AB8A6DF93E8227|
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

***user_relationship_df***

- One useraddress can have relationship with another user(all addresses)

Schema

```
 root
     |-- PARENTUSERIDENTIFIER: string (nullable = true)
     |-- PARENTADDRESSIDENTIFIER: string (nullable = true)
     |-- CHILDUSERIDENTIFIER: string (nullable = true)
     |-- NETWORKIDENTIFIER: string (nullable = true)
```

sample data

```
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|PARENTUSERIDENTIFIER            |PARENTADDRESSIDENTIFIER         |CHILDUSERIDENTIFIER             |NETWORKIDENTIFIER               |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|97B177D33281DF30AFC9924294D1973D|A8EFFB0D29B8628B9A3E993490FF6F8F|C9BBB242202692B589DC5E6AD1040229|0364142E829F4B9384C8023C3BD7194B|
|97B177D33281DF30AFC9924294D1973D|33CF41F3F7AC69029EDD664DF569AE41|C9BBB242202692B589DC5E6AD1040229|0364142E829F4B9384C8023C3BD7194B|
|97B177D33281DF30AFC9924294D1973D|97612FEFFD5EA7664E566161CE9318EF|C9BBB242202692B589DC5E6AD1040229|0364142E829F4B9384C8023C3BD7194B|
|97B177D33281DF30AFC9924294D1973D|0779CA3DCA30B801B55AB8FE8EFE8E77|C9BBB242202692B589DC5E6AD1040229|0364142E829F4B9384C8023C3BD7194B|
|97B177D33281DF30AFC9924294D1973D|0779CA3DCA30B801B55AB8FE8EFE8E77|C9BBB242202692B589DC5E6AD1040229|06702F3EAF8846A450AB8A6DF93E8227|
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

*I have to perform bellow join for getting all Parent child relationship details.*

```
user_relationship_df = user_df.alias('U1').join(
        user_relationship_df.alias('R'),
              [
                  f_col('U1.UserIdentifier') == f_col('R.parentUserIdentifier'),
                  f_col('U1.addressIdentifier') == f_col('R.parentAddressIdentifier'),
                  f_col('U1.networkIdentifier') == f_col('R.networkIdentifier'),
              ],
        'inner'
    ).join(
        user_df.alias('U2'),
        [
            f_col('U2.UserIdentifier') == f_col('R.childUserIdentifier'),
            f_col('U2.networkIdentifier') == f_col('R.networkIdentifier')
        ]
    ).select(
        f_col('U1.UserIdentifier').alias('parentUserIdentifier'),
        f_col('U1.AddressIdentifier').alias('parentAddressIdentifier'),
        f_col('U2.UserName').alias('parentUserName'),
        f_col('U1.latitude').alias('parentlatitude'),
        f_col('U1.longitude').alias('parentlongitude'),
        f_col('U2.UserIdentifier').alias('childUserIdentifier'),
        f_col('U2.AddressIdentifier').alias('childadressIdentifier'),
        f_col('U2.latitude').alias('childlatitude'),
        f_col('U2.longitude').alias('childlongitude'),
        f_col('U2.UserName').alias('childUserName'),
        f_col('R.networkIdentifier').alias('networkIdentifier')
    )
```

**Above join operation is very slow. How can I improve the performance ?**

bellow one is the write operation after join.

expected output after join

```
+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|parentUserIdentifier|parentAddressIdentifier|      parentUserName| parentlatitude|  parentlongitude| childUserIdentifier|childadressIdentifier|  childlatitude|   childlongitude|       childUserName|   networkIdentifier|
+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   33CF41F3F7AC69029...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.610987000000|-117.712710000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 0E30A48D4829E093E...|33.780334000000|-117.863353000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   33CF41F3F7AC69029...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.610987000000|-117.712710000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 086E9420C60A7D037...|33.780334000000|-117.863353000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   33CF41F3F7AC69029...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.610987000000|-117.712710000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 0DC22C71A345C6750...|33.701665000000|-117.956545000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   33CF41F3F7AC69029...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.610987000000|-117.712710000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 0EBFEB7F15B503D7F...|33.804552000000|-118.067973000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   33CF41F3F7AC69029...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.610987000000|-117.712710000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 0B60DA9CB69084711...|33.779730000000|-117.867278000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   97612FEFFD5EA7664...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.569658000000|-117.726847000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 0E30A48D4829E093E...|33.780334000000|-117.863353000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   97612FEFFD5EA7664...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.569658000000|-117.726847000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 086E9420C60A7D037...|33.780334000000|-117.863353000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   97612FEFFD5EA7664...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.569658000000|-117.726847000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 0DC22C71A345C6750...|33.701665000000|-117.956545000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   97612FEFFD5EA7664...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.569658000000|-117.726847000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 0EBFEB7F15B503D7F...|33.804552000000|-118.067973000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   97612FEFFD5EA7664...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.569658000000|-117.726847000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 0B60DA9CB69084711...|33.779730000000|-117.867278000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   0779CA3DCA30B801B...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.665445000000|-117.761503000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 0E30A48D4829E093E...|33.780334000000|-117.863353000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   0779CA3DCA30B801B...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.665445000000|-117.761503000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 086E9420C60A7D037...|33.780334000000|-117.863353000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   0779CA3DCA30B801B...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.665445000000|-117.761503000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 0DC22C71A345C6750...|33.701665000000|-117.956545000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   0779CA3DCA30B801B...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.665445000000|-117.761503000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 0EBFEB7F15B503D7F...|33.804552000000|-118.067973000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   0779CA3DCA30B801B...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.665445000000|-117.761503000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 0B60DA9CB69084711...|33.779730000000|-117.867278000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   A8EFFB0D29B8628B9...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.439137000000|-117.621570000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 0E30A48D4829E093E...|33.780334000000|-117.863353000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   A8EFFB0D29B8628B9...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.439137000000|-117.621570000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 086E9420C60A7D037...|33.780334000000|-117.863353000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   A8EFFB0D29B8628B9...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.439137000000|-117.621570000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 0DC22C71A345C6750...|33.701665000000|-117.956545000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   A8EFFB0D29B8628B9...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.439137000000|-117.621570000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 0EBFEB7F15B503D7F...|33.804552000000|-118.067973000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
|97B177D33281DF30A...|   A8EFFB0D29B8628B9...|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|33.439137000000|-117.621570000000|C9BBB242202692B58...| 0B60DA9CB69084711...|33.779730000000|-117.867278000000|CHOC CHILDRENS SP...|0364142E829F4B938...|
+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+
user_relationship_details_df.coalesce(1000).write.option(
            'maxRecordsPerFile', 100000).mode('overwrite').format('json').save('hdfs_path')
```

pyspark command used to execute.

```
spark-submit script.py
```

Comment: coalesce 1 ....

Comment: Coalesce is causing performance too low.. try to increase based on data volume or size.

Comment: @Srinivas  I have increased coalesce to 1000. But there is no much improvements

Comment: @mck Could you please help me out ?

Comment: can you post some sample data ? for both tables

Comment: @Srinivas I have updated with sample data.

Comment: expected output ?

Comment: thanks, is this input & output matching ?

Comment: @Srinivas Yes,  This is matching inputs and out puts

Comment: I don't understand why relationship dataset contains again address and network identifiers. These two are already provided by user_df right?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to try two things

1. Try to increase the number of partitions in coalesce more than one to enable parallelism which will improve the performance of write operation.
   2.try using partitionby and give the partition column Which will improve the performance of write operation

Comment: Write is not a big deal. Hear join is coursing more slowness.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is with write performance, then instead of using `coalesce()` use   `repartition()`. Coalesce() is meant to decrease the number of partitions where `repartition()` can be used to increase the number of partitions and thereby increase parallelism. If you increase the repartition count very large wont really help until you have enough resources. More details about [coalesce vs repartition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610971/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce)

Comment: joining coursing slowness, not write operation.

Comment: Here are some guidelines to look at for optimizing joins: https://databricks.com/session/optimizing-apache-spark-sql-joins

Also if one of your table is small, then you could do **broadcast** join.