# Spark Repartition and Coalesce

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If I want to repartition a dataframe, How to decide on the **number of partitions** that need to be made? How to decide on whether to use repartition or coalesce?
I understand that coalesce is basically used only to reduce the number of partitions. But how can we decide which to use in what scenario?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark - repartition() vs coalesce()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610971/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce)

Answer (score 0):

we can't decide this based on specific parameter there will be multiple factors are there to decide how many partitions and repartition or coalesce
*based on the size of data ,
if size of the file is too big you can give 2 or 3 partitions per block to
increase the performance but if give more too many partitions it split as
small files .In Big data small files will lower performance .
1 Block (128 MB) --> 128/2 = 64MB each partition ,So 1 mapper will run for 64 MB
*based on the cluster size , if you have more number of executors/cores are free you can give according to that.
*repartition will cause the complete shuffling and coalesce will avoid the complete shuffle.