# Spark Repartition() and Coalesce() internals

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

How does Repartition or Coalesce work internally?

For Repartition() is the data being collected on Drive node and then shuffled across the executors?

Is Coalesce a Narrow/wide transformation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark - repartition() vs coalesce()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610971/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer is helpful - [Spark - repartition() vs coalesce()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610971/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce)

Do read the answer by Powers and Justin